# Cufon textShadow + hover problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cufon

I only want the text-shadow to be on the hover state.

```
**JS**
Cufon.replace('.headerright', {hover: true,'fontFamily' : 'League Gothic',textShadow:'0px 1px #cccccc'});
**CSS**
.headerright{text-transform:uppercase; font-size:76px;color:#CD7674;}
.headerright a:hover{color:#444444;}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've never used cufon, but I think it's now better to start using the @font-face and shadows as part of CSS3... Paul Irish published a bullet proof method that even works with IE (http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)

Comment: Thanks fudgey, will start testing that approach tomorrow, very interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is defining `textShadow` from the get-go rather than for the `hover` event.

Looking at https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/styling, this should work for you:

```
Cufon.replace('.headerright', {
    'fontFamily': 'League Gothic',
    hover: {
        textShadow: '0px 1px #cccccc'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Cufon.replace('.menu_item', {fontFamily: 'museo700_regular',hover: {textShadow: '0px 1px #fff'},textShadow:'0px 1px #fff', hover:true});
```